# Algorithm for reaching target sum using given array of integers such that certain numbers are avoided?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

The exercise is a simple challenging Java program. the input contains:

1. size of an array "n",
2. the inputs for the array A and
3. the inputs for another array B of size "n-1"
4. "finalsum" is sum of all the elements in Array A

What is the most correct algorithm for printing the correct order of adding all the elements in array A to reach the final sum, i.e. "finalsum", such that we avoid summing up to any value in array B.

```
Inputs: (split to three lines for clarity)

1. 

3             //n, the size of the array
2 4 6         //array a of size n
4 8           //array b of size n-1

//finalsum = 2 + 4 + 6 = 12. Similarly for the 2nd input

Output: 0 1 2 (or) 2 1 0 is also correct
        but 1 0 2 is wrong because it cannot add up to 4, since 4 is present in the array b 

2. 

20
20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
209 208 207 206 205 204 203 202 201 200 199 198 197 196 195 194 193 192 191

Output: 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 (or) many other ways too
```

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: It's a bin-packing problem.  Look it up.

Comment: I have attempted to solve the problem and it works for some inputs but it gives ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error for other inputs, I do not understand the condition required to rid the program of this bug.

Comment: The necessary condition is to avoid indexing outside the bounds of the array.  `if (index >= array.length) do something else`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm could look something like this:

1. Take an element from `A`
2. Add element to current sum. Check if current sum is contained in `B`
3. If current sum is in `B`, skip to next element in `A`
4. If current sum NOT in `B`, recurse to select next element from `A` (with current element removed).
5. When all elements from `A` have been selected, return indexes back up the stack as solution.
6. If all elements of `A` have been tested without solution, *AND* we're currently at the top-most level of the recursion stack, then conclude there is no solution.

Most of these steps should be relatively straightforward to implement.

Comment: Tried this method in a slightly different way, i.e. by looking at the array's as set's and performing set operation on it. Works only for certain inputs, while a few others give arrayindexoutofBounds exception.

Comment: Well somewhere you are trying to access an array index outside of the range of the array :)  Have you tried using the debugger in your IDE to see exactly where it is happening?  Is it possible somewhere you accidentally refer to `B` when you mean `A`, since they differ by 1 in size?  Or there could be a logical bug in your set logic, or an off-by-1 index bug?  There are many reasons, but it's going to be in the code, not the algorithm.

Comment: Okay, by your logic, what if at some point during the recursion, all values in A, when added to "current sum", gives a value that is present in B, then we cant simply skip again, because there wouldn't be any more elements left in A to add to "current sum", this portion generates the ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception. Besides, in this scenario, it does not necessarily mean that there is no order available, that would be just plain wrong, rather the order the program has tried to generate turns out to be wrong, but there is still some correct order for every input given the restrictions.

Comment: If there are no elements left to check in A but we're somewhere down the stack, then you return back to the previous level in the recursion (with say an empty set to indicate no solution was found) - I see I'm not entirely clear about that in my rough algorithm.  The only time you conclude that there is no solution is if you've run out of elements to check in `A` *AND* you are also at the top-most level of recursion.  And that has nothing to do with getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` - you need to properly check the bounds as you navigate the array/set/whatever no matter where you're at.

Answer (score 0):

why can't we use the modified form of all permutation algorithm, where check for the sum in each step. if the current sum is equal to any element in B (for this we can use hash map) then don't proceed else proceed.

Hope i am clear.

Thanks.

Comment: the program must follow an algorithm that always returns a good order rather than testing every permutation, this is one of the conditions to build the program. Also, inputs can vary up to maximum of 100, so testing every combination would be very slow, which is not what is intended.

Comment: @Suraj `returns a good order rather than testing every permutation` here what u mean by good order? i think u need all the permutation of numbers where no intermediate sum equals to any number in B.